# Transform two CSS grids to one, where the middle row fills up to bottom of viewport

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a working solutions for my own problem. Which is that I want a variable height header, the main navigation (also variable) and a banner which fills to the bottom of the viewport.

However, if I want to add new grid rows in the `#grid-header` (like content and footer) I am forced to use a new grid. If I add them to the `#grid-header`, the banner will logically not stretch to the bottom of the viewport anymore. This new `#grid-content` starts below the viewport.

Is there a solution to create just one main grid? Where the header and navbar do not have an height declaration, the banner always fills up to the bottom of the viewport and additional rows start below the viewport.

My working CSS-code with two grids:

```
body{
    height:100%;
}
#grid-header{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows:max-content max-content auto; /* full viewport sized banner */
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header header header header header"
        "navbar navbar navbar navbar navbar"
        "banner banner banner banner banner";
    height:100%;
}
#grid-content{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows:max-content max-content;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "content content content content content"
        "footer footer footer footer footer";
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>
    
    <div id="grid-header">
        
        <!-- GRID MAIN DESIGN ELEMENTS-->
        <div id="design-header"></div>
        <div id="design-nav"></div>
        <div id="design-banner"></div>
        
        <!-- GRID CONTENTS -->
        <header id="header">
            Header
        </header>
        
        <nav id="nav-main">
            1 2 3 4 5
        </nav>

        <section id="banner">
            <div id="presentation">
                <div class="slide">
                    Slide 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        
    </div>
    
    <div id="grid-content">
    
        <!-- GRID MAIN DESIGN ELEMENTS-->
        <div id="design-content"></div>
        <div id="design-footer"></div>
        
        <!-- GRID CONTENTS -->
        <section id="content">Content</section>
        <footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
        
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: No...because your banner needs to know the height of the previous items in order to stretch to 100vh (less those items). If it doesn't know those it won't work.

Comment: It does work. To me what matters is the addition of two new rows below the banner. Whilst the banner still stretches to the viewport. This is because of the 100% height and grid-template-rows: auto;

Comment: My point is that *it won't work with a single grid*.